# How I can integrate Quick Blox video chat service on my Android app?

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I want to integrate the video chat service of Quick Blox on my Android application. The documentation available of Quick Blox just shows how to put the SDK on the app, not how to implement (clearly) step-by-step video chat. It gives a code with a sample of the video chat, but I would like a tutorial or some like this. Can anybody help me?

Comment: There is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3DOZjRtwOY) on building the QuickBlox Android Chat sample. Although it is for chat (not calls), it gives a basic idea on how to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved to put the all sample project of video chat of Quick Blox on my app.